# Div with transform rotate drifts on div that shold be above it

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that it seems i can find a solution for, I have a simple html table with some css, that looks like:

```css
.module-table {
    line-height: 1.2em;
    border: solid thin;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 11.5px;
    display: table;
}

.module-table th {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid thin;
    width: 100px;
}

.module-table td {
    border: solid thin;
}

.module-table-extended-rack-info {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.module-table-cell {
    border: solid thin;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.module-table-rack-info.module-table-cell {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table class="module-table module-table-cell">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">
                <div>
                    ID: 0
                </div>
            </th>
            <th colspan="3">Modules</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 10px">No.</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Communication</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="8">
                <div class="module-table-rack-info">
                    Row: 0<br>
                    Interval: 12<br>
                    Errors: 0
                </div>
                <div class="module-table-extended-rack-info">
                    Type: Unknown Type
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Ok</td>
            <td>
                4
                0
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Ok</td>
            <td>
                4
                0
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Ok</td>
            <td>
                4
                0
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Ok</td>
            <td>
                4
                0
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>Ok</td>
            <td>
                4
                0
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>Ok</td>
            <td>
                4
                0
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>Ok</td>
            <td>
                4
                0
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I think my problem is visible at first glance, in first column there is a text I rotate by 90 degrees, and there is a normal text, and those divs are colliding. Now what I am trying to do is make normal text above transformed one so it will make one nice column. From what I have done I see problem lies somewhere in .module-table-cell class I tried to override it with other class but no luck. Is there any way to make it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do that.

1: transform its origin

```
.module-table-extended-rack-info {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 40px -4px;
}
```

2: Using Positions

```
.module-table td {
  border: solid thin;
  position: relative;
}
.module-table-extended-rack-info {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```